# How to return integer value from Asp.Net Wep Api using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-web-api

This is my Controller to return Department Id of some products

```
public class DepartmentIdController : ApiController
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        public int GetDeptId(int prodId)
        {
            return db.Products.Where(c => c.ProductId) == prodId).Select(d => d.DepartmentId).FirstOrDefault();
        }

    }
```

I want to return this departmentId value in java funtion to use it inside another  functions and calculations
I'am trying like this but not working..and I'am not good at javaScript...

```
 function DepId(prId) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/Api/DepartmentId?prodId="+prId,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (result) {
                    return result;
                }
            });

        }
```

but nothin happen, nothing returns...
Thank you in advance

Comment: not good at java? or javascript?

Comment: @Alex haha.. I mean JavaScript offcourse

Comment: check console..

Comment: Add some debuggers.  Check if the controller method is being hit.  Debug into the js and see what is in `result`.

Comment: Have you defined Route /Api/DepartmentId ?  I don't see it.  You can check in Chrome console, this ajax call will be throwing not found html error. DeptId method should be preceded by [Route("~/Api/DepartmentId ")]
[HttpGet()]

Comment: @AllenKing If I run this direct on my browser let say productionId 3
http://localhost:49851/Api/DepartmentId?prodId=3  Then I get returned DepartmentId in Json but not in my Javascript function.
Do you mean guys my Javascript looks OK?

Comment: @JonasWillander after running ajax code, right button click on chrome, Inspect and see console.  There must be an HTML error.

Comment: @AllenKing My controller there is no message. When I run debug I can se controller is returning value. But How to use value of this from Javascript? Letsay I want to input it in alert funtion. Is this the right way var dep = DepId(3); and then alert(dep); ? How to save this value in a variable? I mean from function to variable in javascript.?

Comment: Make sure the `prId` value is properly defined (debug into the function using the browser console).

Comment: @nurdyguy thank you, it's says undefined. How to define it?

Comment: Look at the code that is calling the function and see why it isn't passing the value.

Comment: @nurdyguy My controlle rcode is passing but then I don't what is happening in java side. Can you tell me how to save function value to a variable? For example letsay  var d = DepId(3); and then if you want to se if d got a value from DepiId(3) you just write alert(d); Is that right? I'am geting undefine

Comment: Your controller is fine (since you can type the url in the browser and it works).  The issue is in the javascript.  Please post the javascript code that calls the `DepId` javascript function.  Basically we found a spot where the variable is incorrect so we need to work backwards to find the error.

Comment: @nurdyguy thank you my dear, I solved it by writing the hole code inside another function rhat givs med productId. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @JonasWillander  instead of return result, can you try alert(result) to see what is being returned.